Is it possible to remove the use of the security code when I log into my Gmail account using a different device?
Is it possible to remove the use of the security code when I log into my Gmail account using a different device? 
There have been two situations where I did not have my phone and was unable to log into my Gmail account due to the need for a security code sent to my phone or email.

Can you [edit] your question to clarify if you have a alternate verification in mind or simply want to opt out from verification at all.
